# For loop in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform

I am trying to get the value of function name from local.tf but I am not able to get it. I have terraform,tfvars in which I am giving the function name then it is passed to variable.tf. From varibale.tf I pass it to local.tf then to main.tf. I am not able to get the function name in main.tf. Any help would be appreciated.
terraform.tfvars

```
config = {
  s3= {
//s3 configurations
}
  s3_notifications = {
      function_name         = "test-lambda-mary"
    }
}
```

variable.tf

```
variable "config" {
  type        = any
  description = "S3 configuration block"
}
```

local.tf

```
  function_name = {
    for k, v in var.config :
    k => lookup(v, "function_name", "")
  }
```

```
module "all_notifications" {
  source   = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws//modules/notification"
  for_each = var.config
  bucket   = module.s3_bucket[each.key].this_s3_bucket_id

  lambda_notifications = {
    lambda = {
      function_name = local.function_name[each.key]
      function_arn  = "arn:aws:lambda:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:function:${local.function_name[each.key]}"
      events        = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]

    }
  }
}
```

error

```
"function_name" doesn't comply with restrictions ("^(arn:[\\w-]+:lambda:)?([a-z]{2}-(?:[a-z]+-){1,2}\\d{1}:)?(\\d{12}:)?(function:)?([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(:(\\$LATEST|[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+))?$"): ""
│ 
│   with module.all_notifications["s3"].aws_lambda_permission.allow["lambda"],
│   on .terraform/modules/all_notifications/modules/notification/main.tf line 63, in resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow":
│   63:   function_name       = each.value.function_name
```

Comment: Ok, but what is the problem? Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin I have added the error in the question

Comment: If I put the function_name inside s3 braces it works absolutely fine but I need to have the fucntion name in s3_notification

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear. What is `each.key` and `module.s3_bucket`? Can you provide values for all variables that you use?

Comment: It creating multiple s3 buckets and adding notification to it

Answer (score 1):

> If I put the function_name inside s3 braces it works absolutely fine but I need to have the fucntion name in s3_notification

That looks like a great hint. You're iterating over `var.config` which has 2 keys and only 1 of them has `function_name` defined. So when module is requested with `s3` as a key, the `function_value` for that key will be empty string and AWS will fail the request as expected.

You can filter `for_each = var.config` to exclude such case, something like:

```
for_each = { for k, v in var.config: k => v if local.function_name[each.key] != ""}
```

Little nitpick: seems like the source of the module could be incorrectly written. Instead of `terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws//modules/notification` potentially it should be `terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket//modules/notification`. See https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket

Comment: Yes you got it right the var.config has two variable, can you help me with the format the solution you provided is right but I need to have it in my format. I am looping over the variable in local.tf like this `  function_name = {
    for k, v in var.config :
    k => lookup(v, "function_name", "")
  }`
How can I adjust the if condidtion in between?

Comment: You can adjust the condition by adding `if lookup(v, "function_name", "") != ""` so that you'll have only 1 element in the `local.function_name`. However you'll need to adjust for_each over the module, because it will be called 2 times while local will have only 1 item. If you add missing code for `module.s3_bucket` and especially what variable it uses for its for_loop it would be more clear question.

Comment: When I add this  `function_name = {
    for k, v in var.config :
    k => if lookup(v, "function_name", "") != ""
  }`
It give me this error `Error: Invalid 'for' expression
│ 
│   on locals.tf line 17, in locals:
│   15:   function_name = {
│   16:     for k, v in var.config :
│   17:     k => if lookup(v, "function_name", "") != ""
│ 
│ Extra characters after the end of the 'for' expression.`

Answer (score 0):

A stab in the dark as I haven't used that module before.

But by looking at your error message:

```
"function_name" doesn't comply with restrictions ("^(arn:[\\w-]+:lambda:)?
```

it looks like for `function_name` you should pass Lambda's ARN, not name (contrary to what the variable name says).

BTW, is `function_arn` even a parameter here?

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming since terraform module is expecting a valid and mandatory function name to create `[aws_lambda_permission][1]` resource using `terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws//modules/notification` module.

In your case you are looping the module on `var.config` which consist s3 and s3_notifications part and while first iteration its getting function name as null therefore its throwing this error.

```
"function_name" doesn't comply with restrictions ("^(arn:[\\w-]+:lambda:)?([a-z]{2}-(?:[a-z]+-){1,2}\\d{1}:)?(\\d{12}:)?(function:)?([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(:(\\$LATEST|[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+))?$"): ""
```

Better split the variable specific to s3_notification as list and iterate the module as below using count.

```
variable "s3_config" {
  type = any
  default = {
    s3 = {

    }
  }
}

variable "s3_notify_lambda_func" {
  type = list
  default = ["test-lambda-mary","test"]. #N Numbers of functions
}

data "aws_region" "current" {}
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

module "all_notifications" {
  source   = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws//modules/notification"
  count = length(var.s3_notify_lambda_func) > 0 ? length(var.s3_notify_lambda_func) : 0
  bucket   = module.s3_bucket[count.index].this_s3_bucket_id

  lambda_notifications = {
    lambda = {
      function_name = var.s3_notify_lambda_func[count.index]
      function_arn  = "arn:aws:lambda:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:function:${var.s3_notify_lambda_func[count.index]}"
      events        = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]

    }
  }
}
```